# Как убрать перенос элементов на новую строку

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть такая лента:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В ней есть еще 5 игр (таких же блоков с картинками и текстом), но они, из-за недостатка ширины страницы, переносятся на новую строчку(overflow: hidden, поэтому их не видно). Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы они не переносились, и при нажатии на стрелочки список листался.

Как убрать перенос на новую строчку(я пробовал ставить ширину родительскому элементу в 1000px, но они все равно переносились).

Блоки с display: inline-block;

Comment: white-space: nowrap; Не?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задайте родительскому элементу свойство `white-space: nowrap`. Оно запрещает перенос дочерних строчных и блочно-строчных элементов на новую строку.

Answer (score 0):

Вы просите написать готовый слайдер. Вряд ли кто-то захочет тратить своё время на это, как и я, поэтому я просто советую Вам посмотреть принцип его создания [на ютубе](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=casgv9Y8I1w) или поискать в интернете способы [создания слайдера на css](https://habr.com/ru/post/324034/), а если знаете jquery/js, то [можно и на js](http://cccp-blog.com/koding/js-slajder). Вот самый простой и доступный [пример слайдера](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgrCb3okKhY), который лично я видел в первые минуты поиска в интернете. Возникшие вопросы по методам можно (не всегда без труда) [попытаться прояснить](https://jquery-docs.ru/). Сделав это своими руками - вы поймете принцип его создания и самое главное - запомните как это должно выглядеть.

Comment: или взять уже готовый https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/